# is postgresql nested exception possible?

Tags: postgresql, exception, psql

i am using postgrest exception in function 'public.main_function'. in exception 'others', i also use sub functions to save my log data.

but my sub function 'public.something_went_wrong_log_creation' might be error sometimes.

how can i add exception (nested exception) in exception 'others' below?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.main_function(request json)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
    -- statement 1
    -- statement 2
    -- statement 3

    RETURN 1;

EXCEPTION
    -- SOMETHING WENT WRONG
    WHEN others
    THEN
        -- LOG SOMETHING WENT WRONG
        PERFORM public.something_went_wrong_log_creation();

        RETURN 0;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

---

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.something_went_wrong_log_creation()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
    -- statement 1
    -- statement 2
    -- statement 3

    RETURN 1;

EXCEPTION
        -- SOMETHING WENT WRONG
        WHEN others
        THEN
            RETURN 0;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subblock and wrap your exception handling code in it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.main_function(request json)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
    -- statement 1
    -- statement 2
    -- statement 3

    RETURN 1;

EXCEPTION
    -- SOMETHING WENT WRONG
    WHEN others
    THEN
        BEGIN
          -- LOG SOMETHING WENT WRONG
          PERFORM public.something_went_wrong_log_creation();

          RETURN 0;
        EXCEPTION
             WHEN others
             THEN
               RETURN -1;
        END;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```